# department table returns null values but I want only non-null department record, pls help :)

Tags: postgresql

[Obtain the department table where more than 38 employees work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFoGu.png)

```
select distinct department,(select count(employee_id)
                  from employees as e1
                  where e2.department= e1.department and 
                   department is not null
                  having count(employee_id) > 38 )
from employees as e2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to look a lot easier. In any case, a sample data and the desired output wouldn't be superfluous.

```
Select department, count(distinct employee_id) as cnt
From employees
Group by department
Having count(distinct employee_id)>38
```